# can not gem install do_mysql. no mysql directory exists

Tags: mysql, ruby, header, rubygems, rhel

I want to `gem install do_mysql`, it fails because the MySQL header files can not be found.

```
do_mysql.c:5:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
do_mysql.c:6:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
do_mysql.c:7:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory"
```

My system adminstrator install mysql as a package, so basically the "/usr/local/mysql" do not exist at all!!

So what should I do?

by querying the package

```
rpm -q --filesbypkg mysql-5.5.19-1.el6.remi.x86_64
mysql                     /usr/bin/msql2mysql
mysql                     /usr/bin/mysql
mysql                     /usr/bin/mysql_config
mysql                     /usr/bin/mysql_find_rows
mysql                     /usr/bin/mysql_waitpid
mysql                     /usr/bin/mysqlaccess
mysql                     /usr/bin/mysqladmin
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the "developer package" of MySQL on your distribution which contains the required header files (your error message contains pointers at `mysql.h`).

On RHEL 6 or compatible distribution you can just install the package `mysql-devel`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried to do  "yum install mysql-devel" but it requires root. My system administrator is unapproachable currently.So is there any work-around?

Comment: You could probably place the MySQL header files in another directory and tell `gem` to also look there for them with the flag `--with-mysql-include=[...]`.